# Apex 4.2 public page

Tags: oracle-apex, access-rights

I didn't found how to make public page the page 0 from oracle apex 4.2.

How i make the page 0 of Apex 4.2 (4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.2.3, 4.2.4, 4.2.5) public page ?

Best regards!

Comment: Actually, A Global Page/Page Zero is a special page.
 Unlike all other pages it has no processes, validations, branches or Security Features.
 It functions as a master page in that APEX renders all the components you add to this page onto every page within your application.
 And just like virtually all the other parts in your application you can define your own conditions on the page and its components. So you can now create a region once and it will display on as many pages in your application as you want rather than you having to create it on every page.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your application, and click **Create Page**. Then select **Global Page** en use page number 0.

However, it is not a public page, it is a global page. That means that all other pages include the elements that page 0 has as well.